How to get the Azure Automation Runbook Job Id in a Python Runbook?
Powershell Runbooks allow you to get the Job ID with $PSPrivateMetadata.JobId.Guid
How do we get it if the runbook is Python?

Can you provide code that you have tried?

@RithwikBojja I haven't tried anything. I have no idea how to reference it. I can't find any documentation about this.

This is what you need.
To retrieve the Azure Automation Runbook Job Id in a Python Runbook, you can use the AutomationJobId environment variable that is automatically provided by Azure Automation. Here's how you can access the Runbook Job Id in a Python script within an Azure Automation Runbook:
import os

#get the Runbook Job Id from the AutomationJobId environment variable
runbook_job_id = os.environ.get('AutomationJobId')

if runbook_job_id:
    print(f'Runbook Job Id: {runbook_job_id}')
else:
    print('Runbook Job Id not found')

In the code snippet, I used the os.environ.get() method to retrieve the value of the AutomationJobId environment variable, which contains the unique identifier of the current job being executed in Azure Automation. You can then use this runbook_job_id variable to track or log the job id as needed within your Python script.

Thanks! I'll try it and get back to you. Where did you find this information?

Well as a software engineer, I've hit this rock wall before and tried in vain to find credible documentation, I figured it myself. To be honest you're the best solution to your own problem if you think hard enough.

Probably I need to know more about python to figure it out (I just started learning). Thanks for the help, brother!

@richard I'll appreciate if you can mark it as the answer and allocate the bounty points, thank you.

Ok - Dexter looks like that doesn't work. I tried it and it's just blank.

Well I have used it on my end for a while now and still works, you might need to check your set up...

Any leads on this? This is really annoying that half of the functionality is not there in python based runbook which you can have in powershell based runbooks

According to the API documentation, you can create a Python Runbook using runbook = azure.mgmt.automation.models.Runbook(<options>), then access the runbook.id property.
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-automation/azure.mgmt.automation.models.runbook?view=azure-python

I have a runbook created already in the portal. And what I need is the job id, not the runbook Id. I can get the Runbook Id already.

Maybe you want azure.mgmt.automation.models.Job().job_id?

Linux:
import sys, string, os, subprocess

jobid=subprocess.check_output('pwsh -cwa "$PSPrivateMetadata.JobId.Guid"',shell=True) #calls a powershell subprocess and the output is stored on jobid

print(jobid) #This is should be the Job ID

Edit:
Windows:
The command line to run powershell command in Windows CMD should be like this:
import sys, string, os, subprocess
jobif=subprocess.check_output('powershell -command "$PSPrivateMetadata.JobId.Guid"', shell=True) 
print(jobid)


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Got an error 'pwsh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/src/tmp/5691c839-9523-48d2-b93c-e8a729b2fc1d/runbooks/EnqueueDataImportConfigurationIntegrationTask.py", line 11, in  jobid=subprocess.check_output('pwsh -cwa "$PSPrivateMetadata.JobId.Guid"',shell=True) File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py"

You could try to look for a CMD command to get the powershell response as you want it and put it instead of 'powershell -command "$PSPrivateMetadata.JobId.Guid"'
